# Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise Publish Window

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2019

When publishing a .NET project in Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise, I encountered a window where I expected to find the "Self-contained" option to obtain a .dll file. However, I couldn't locate this option in the window.

[image]

I encountered a problem while trying to publish my .NET project in Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise. When going through the publishing process, I expected to find the "Self-contained" option in the publish window, which would allow me to obtain a single .dll file as part of the deployment. However, I couldn't locate this option and it's causing difficulty in achieving the desired result.

Here are the steps I took:

Right-clicked on my project in the Solution Explorer and selected "Publish."

In the subsequent windows, I expected to find the "Self-contained" option in the available settings, but it was not present.
I have checked for any missing dependencies or extensions and ensured that I'm using the latest version of Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise. However, I still couldn't find the "Self-contained" option in the publish window.

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and locate the "Self-contained" option. I'm aiming to obtain a single .dll file for my deployment. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Is this a .NET or .NET Framework project?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55229364/20376806) mentions self-container. This doesn't seem to be a button or option, you need to set SelfContained to true in the pubxml file. If you set selfcontained to false, you will see that no exe is generated. If this is not what you want please tell me whether your project uses .net framework or .net. And what documents are you referring to for publishing operations?